# Python : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python-2.7, linked-list

I am trying to merge 2 sorted linked list into single sorted linked list.

```
class Node:
    # Function to initialise the node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data =data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
       def mergeNode(self, second_list):
        llist4 = LinkedList()
        first_node = self.head
        second_node = second_list.head

        while (first_node!=None or second_node != None):
            if (first_node.data > second_node.data):

                    llist4.push(first_node)
                    prev = first_node
                    first_node = first_node.next

            elif (first_node.data < second_node.data):

                    llist4.push(second_node)
                    prev = second_node
                    second_node = second_node.next

        else:
                llist4.push(first_node)
                llist4.push(second_node)
                prev = second_node
                second_node = second_node.next
                first_node = first_node.next
        return llist4

if __name__ == '__main__':

    llist = LinkedList()
    llist2 = LinkedList()
    llist3 = LinkedList()

    llist.push(15)
    llist.push(10)
    llist.push(5)

    llist2.push(12)
    llist2.push(3)
    llist2.push(2)
        llist3 = llist.mergeNode(llist2)
    llist3.printList()
```

But I am getting error as :
`" AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'"`
 I am aware that I might be using None value in my code by I am not able to figure out the reason. Someone please help me to find out the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: I have already gone through link "Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'" am aware that I am trying to use None value in my code but I am not able to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first_node!=None or second_node != None` does not guarantee that both values are `None`.

```
first_node = None
second_node = "something"
print first_node!=None or second_node != None  # True
```

Use proper condition:

```
while first_node is not None and second_node is not None:
    do_something()
```